# How to flip the orientation of beamsplitter in pst-optexp package

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I was trying to plot an interferometer in latex using pst-optexp package. Everything works fine the beamsplitter is in the wrong orientation and need to be fliped 90 degree. However, the command`\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS,label = 0.8 -45](A)(BS)(PD){BS}` does not work. Does anyone know how to rotate the beamsplitter in that package?

The code I used is

```
\documentclass[margin=36pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
\pnodes(0,3){S}(1,3){LS}(2,3){A}(3,3){BS}(5,3){M1}(3,5){M2}(3,1){PD}
\optbox[abspos = 0.5, optboxsize=1 0.5, labeloffset = 0](S)(LS){Laser}
\lens[compname=L0, lensradius=0.5 0.5, lensheight = 0.5, abspos = 0.2, n=2,thicklens = false](LS)(A){obj}
\pinhole[compname = PH, labeloffset = -0.7](LS)(A){Pinhole}
\lens[compname=L1, abspos = 1, n=2, thicklens = false](LS)(A){Lens1}

\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS,label = 0.8 -45](A)(BS)(PD){BS}
\optbox[abspos = 1.75, optboxsize=0.5 0.5, label = 0.7 180](BS)(M1){Sample}
\mirror[compname=M1,labeloffset = 1](BS)(M1)(BS){Test Arm}
\mirror[compname=M2, mirrortype=piezo](BS)(M2)(BS){Ref Arm}
\lens[compname=L2, label = 1 180](BS)(PD){Lens2}
\optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=round, label = 0.5 90,abspos = 2.5](BS)(PD){Camera}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid, linecolor = red, fillcolor=red, opacity = 0.2}
\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L2}{Det}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting picture is [image: the orientation of beam splitter is wrong]. The example given in pst-optexp manual is wrong in the same way.

Comment: After fixing beamsplitter orientation problem, how to draw raypath for two branches. I used `\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M1}{BS}{L2}{Det} \drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L2}{Det}` and it only draws one branch. @Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three nodes of a `\beamsplitter` are the source, center of the beamsplitter and the target of the reflected beam. The reflective interface is rotated accordingly.

So if the beam should come from `A`, is reflected at `BS` and then goes to `M2`, your beamsplitter should be

```
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS](A)(BS)(M2){BS}
```

The full example, with the two `\drawwidebeam` calls is:

```
\documentclass[margin=36pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
\pnodes(0,3){S}(1,3){LS}(2,3){A}(3,3){BS}(5,3){M1}(3,5){M2}(3,1){PD}
\optbox[abspos = 0.5, optboxsize=1 0.5, labeloffset = 0](S)(LS){Laser}
\lens[compname=L0, lensradius=0.5 0.5, lensheight = 0.5, abspos = 0.2, n=2,thicklens = false](LS)(A){obj}
\pinhole[compname = PH, labeloffset = -0.7](LS)(A){Pinhole}
\lens[compname=L1, abspos = 1, n=2, thicklens = false](LS)(A){Lens1}

\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS,label = 0.8 -45](A)(BS)(M2){BS}
\optbox[abspos = 1.75, optboxsize=0.5 0.5, label = 0.7 180](BS)(M1){Sample}
\mirror[compname=M1,labeloffset = 1](BS)(M1)(BS){Test Arm}
\mirror[compname=M2, mirrortype=piezo](BS)(M2)(BS){Ref Arm}
\lens[compname=L2, label = 1 180](BS)(PD){Lens2}
\optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=round, label = 0.5 90,abspos = 2.5](BS)(PD){Camera}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid, linecolor = red, fillcolor=red, opacity = 0.2}

\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M1}{BS}{L2}{Det}
\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L2}{Det}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Christoph Thank you for the answer. One minor follow up question: after fixing beamsplitter orientation, I try to redraw the ray path using `\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M1}{BS}{L2}{Det}
\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L2}{Det}` and it only draws one branch. Do you know why?

Comment: Works fine for me. I updated the answer with the full modified example, including both `\drawwidebeam` calls that you want.

Comment: @Christoph Doesn't work for me. I see only one branch running that code on Overleaf.

Comment: @Rodrigo I also couldn't get it to work properly on Overleaf: With `LaTeX` as compiler, it basically works, but without transparency, because `-dNOSAFER` is not passed during conversion (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491028/33933). And `pdfLaTeX` with `auto-pst-pdf` seems not to be supported at Overleaf, see also their statement at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Choosing_a_LaTeX_Compiler#Other_compilers

Comment: @Christoph I guess I'll stick to tikz when using Overleaf.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ok, I'm sorry to hear that. But I cannot manage it to make the package work with XeLaTeX.